# How to decrypt and divert traffic through L2 devices with Avi Networks?

Tags: encryption, load-balancing

When using Avi Networks controller, is it possible to

1. receive SSL/TLS traffic from the client,
2. decrypt the traffic (maybe selectively),
3. divert the traffic through an active L2 device (such as IPS for filtering)
4. receive cleaned traffic back,
5. re-ecnrypt it,
6. send it forward to the destination server?

The decryption/encryption part is sometimes referred to as SSL Forward Proxy.

Here's an example of this feature https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/divert-unencrypted-traffic-through-an-ips-with-local-traffic-manager

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the capabilities of a specific product and has nothing to do with the [topics which can be asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I would suggest that you actually ask the vendor for such product specific questions.

Comment: This is because they are actually encouraging posting questions on StackOverflow, see http://info.avinetworks.com/community

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Avi Networks SE, it turns out this feature is not supported at this time.